# Is npm install the same as npm install --save?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm looking at the doc page for node and I'm not clear if

```
npm install gulp-util
```

is the same as

```
npm install gulp-util --save
```

In the doc it says:

"By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json"

That feels like what --save does,

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just running `npm install` with no arguments, will install everything listed in the `dependencies` area of the package.json file.

Running `npm install <package-name>` will install that package only, and will *not* add the package to the dependencies list in package.json

Running `npm install <package-name> --save` will install that package only, and will add the package to the dependencies list.

### Update for npm 5+:

Running `npm install <package-name>` will install that package, and will add the package to the dependencies list.

Comment: This used to be true. [NPM version 5 adds --save by default now](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500). To be clear, ```npm install <package name>`` without the --save will still add the package to your package .json

Comment: stackoverflow should add an option to mark accepted answer as deprecated, and can accept new answer.

Answer (score 10):

`npm install` without specifying a package name will install the dependencies in your `package.json`.

`npm install gulp-util` will install gulp-util without modifying your package.json.

`npm install gulp-util --save` will install gulp-util and update your package.json, so that in the future when you or someone else runs `npm install`, they will install gulp-util without needing to specify it. `package.json` keeps track of your project's dependencies, so that you only have to run `npm install` after a fresh clone/pull/deployment/reinstall/whatever, instead of needing to manually install all dependencies by specifying their names.